# Convert select result that has JSON field to JSON and use that data with JSON_VALUE()

Tags: json, sql-server, json-query, json-value

I have a table that has some columns.
One of these columns stores data in JSON format.
I select a row from this table with `FOR JSON AUTO`.
My problem is that SQL Server puts quotations around the value of JSON properties but I don't want this; because I want to use the values of inner JSON with `JSON_VALUE()`. What can I do?

Code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM users;
```

Result:

```
name    lastName    age    favorites
John    Duo         20     {"city": "paris", "color": "blue", "sport": "football"}
```

Code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM users
FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Result:

```
{"name":"John","lastName":"Duo","age":20,"favorites":"{\"city\": \"paris\", \"color\": \"blue\", \"sport\": \"football\"}"}
```

Code:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@user_json,'$.favorites.color')
```

Result:

```
NULL
```

I can use this trick to get values from inner JSON, but it's not clean.

Code:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(@user_json,'$.favorites'), '$.color')
```

Result:

```
blue
```

How can I do this in a clean way?

Some code for testing in SQL Server:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test_tbl;
DECLARE @user_json AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
  
SELECT 'John' AS Name, 'Duo' AS LastName, 20 AS Age, '{"city": "paris", "color": "blue", "sport": "football"}' AS favorites
INTO #test_tbl;

SET @user_json =
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #test_tbl
    FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@user_json,'$.favorites.color');

SELECT JSON_VALUE(JSON_VALUE(@user_json,'$.favorites'),'$.color');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest the favorites JSON using `json_query()`, e.g.:

```sql
SET @user_json =
(
    SELECT Name, LastName, Age, json_query(favorites) as favorites
    FROM #test_tbl
    FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@user_json,'$.favorites.color');

# (No column name)
# ----------------
# blue
```

Comment: My columns are in change and I want to use * sign to have all columns in my JSON.

Comment: You can't do that @MohammadHoseinMasoon . SQL queries need to be well defined *before* they are run, not defined as they run. *You* need to define what columns you want in your dataset; there is no magic "SELECT {any column without defined structure} FROM...` syntax.